# Use Displayport-Splitter to connect two computers to one Displayport jack of a monitor

Tags: mac, display, displayport, splitter

I have here a Windows computer (Lenovo W510) and a MacBook Pro (Early 2011). Now I want to connect each Displayport output of the computers to one Displayport input of the monitor (iiyama PL2779Q). So the Windows computer has a standard Displayport output and the Mac has a Mini-Displayport output. Both outputs should be connected to one Displayport input of the monitor.

The reason is that I want to use the full resolution of `2560x1440 px`, so I don't want to use another port. Also a Dual-Link-DVI adapter is very expensive. Therefore I tried [this adapter](http://www.delock.de/produkte/F_658_Displayport_61751/merkmale.html), but it didn't worked. From the connectivity standpoint it should work. I don't want to use both computers at the same time and I don't want to switch the monitor cables every time.

Is the only option an expensive KVM-Switch? I don't need keyboard/mouse/audio connectivity, because Audio would be over Displayport and I have external Bluetooth accessories (trackpad, keyboard).

**Edit:**

I come up with the following options:

1. KVM-Switch: expensive, but it would do the work. Additional adapter if you use the Mini-DP of the Mac.
2. Displayport to Dual Link DVI Adapter: expensive, no sound
3. Software - Remote Desktop: resolution? clamshell mode? Why network if the device is right beside you? If it would work, it would be the cheapest solution.
4. Buy a new monitor: expensive

Also you have to think which connections will be outdated soon. Hmmm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DisplayPort splitters are actually about the same price as dual-link DVI adapters.  I would recommend you invest in the DVI cable and run audio to the screen separately for whichever computer you use it on.

Even if you hooked it up with a splitter and managed to get it working (I don't think it would, BTW), you'd have no way to "switch" back and forth between the two computers.  You'd be putting yourself in the situation of having to make sure one was off while using the other as there's no telling what might happen if you accidentally tried using them both at the same time.  If you didn't want to shut one down to use the other, you'd be constantly plugging/unplugging cables.

I think it would just be far more convenient to use different inputs on the screen for different sources.