# Display Port Monitor and Two Regular Display Port Computers

Tags: display, displayport, splitter

I have 1 Display Port Monitor and 2 Display Port Computers. What is the best way to toggle between the two computers for the monitor view? I do not want to switch wires, etc. Are there other solutions beside KVM switches for Displayport. Many of them are getting bad reviews.

This article is for DisplayPort and Minidisplayport,  wondering if solution can be different or if anything has changed in 3 years?

[Use Displayport-Splitter to connect two computers to one Displayport jack of a monitor](https://superuser.com/questions/902816/use-displayport-splitter-to-connect-two-computers-to-one-displayport-jack-of-a-m)

Answer (score 1):

The solution in the article you mentioned in your post is still correct nowadays.
You can use an expensive KVM switch, but is far more convenient to use another input on your screen, because, unfortunately, there aren't any "passive" switchers available (or at least I coudn't find one for sale in Amazon)